# How QApplication() and QWidget() objects are connected in PySide/PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

How QApplication() and QWidget() are connected?

This is an example code that I copied, it creates QApplication object and QWidget object, but there is no link between the two objects. I expected something like `app.setWidget(did)` to teach PySide/PyQt controller about the widget that was created.

```
# http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/firstprograms/
# 1. PySide.QtGui is the class
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

# 2. setup the application
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

# 3. create the widget and setup 
wid = QtGui.QWidget()
wid.resize(250, 150)
wid.setWindowTitle('Simple')

# 4. Show the widget 
wid.show()

# 5. execute the app
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What's the magic behind this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`QApplication` is a singleton so it would be pretty easy, for `QWidget` to do: `QApplication.instance()` and interact with the `QApplication` instance.

In fact trying to instantiate `QWidget` before the `QApplication` leads to an error:

```
>>> QtGui.QWidget()
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

Which probably means this is what happens.

---

**Edit:** I've downloaded the qt sources and in fact, in `src/gui/kernel/qwidget.cpp`, line 328, there is:

```
if (!qApp) {
    qFatal("QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice");
    return;
}
```

Where `qApp` is a pointer to the `QApplication` instance(i.e. it is equivalent to calling `QApplication.instance()`).

So, in the end, the `QWidget` interacts with the `QApplication` via a global variable, even though it isn't necessary. They probably use `qApp` instead of `QApplication.instance()` to avoid unnecessary overhead that might happen when creating/destroying many `QWidget`s.