# Python - How do I get my GUI to display in Spyder

Tags: python, pyqt, ipython, spyder

I'm new to creating GUI's in Python and can't seem to get over the first hurdle.
I'm using Anaconda - Spyder and I normally run all (mainly mathematical) code through this (and the IPython console?).

My issue is that when I run the code below I'm expecting it to display a simple blank window but nothing happens.

Is Spyder/IPython not the best way to do this or is there an issue with my code?

I've tried using the command prompt by typing "python TestScript.py" whilst in the correct directory but I get an error saying 'Python is not recognised as a internal or external command'. Do I need to set up cmd to use Anaconda?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250,150)
    w.move(30,30)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple Window')
    w.show

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: adding  **`()`**  after `w.show` might help

Comment: Welcom to SO. Great first post - clear and concise. You should have googled/SO-Searched for QApplication before asking, you would have seen lots of results (f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601896/how-qapplication-and-qwidget-objects-are-connected-in-pyside-pyqt ) with running code - and compared it to yours which would have made the error obvious.  :)

Comment: Thanks Patrick after all that it was a simple case of two brackets!

I did have a good go at searching for an answer but I was thinking it was more to do with my set up of Spyder/settings etc..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing this one up, as the answer was posted in the comments by Patrick Artner.

Simply adding () after w.show solved the problem.